# How to save contents of filtered list in text document

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to save a list of users to a file on a network drive and want the name to be removed from the text file when the user exits the program. Whenever I run it only the last name in the list is saved to the file. Here is what I have tried

```
def move_offline(self):
    with open("usercheck.txt", "r") as self.text, open("user.txt", "r") as exc:
        exclusions = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in exc]
        for line in self.text:
            if not any(exclusion in line for exclusion in exclusions):
                #print (line)
                self.gg = [line.strip("\n")]
                print (self.gg)
```

This Function is just to determine what the username is and if it is present in the file on the network file

```
def actmov(self):
    try:
        mmm = open("usercheck.txt","w")
        mmm.writelines(["%s\n"%item for item in self.gg])
    except AttributeError:
        print ("Oops, something didnt save correctly!")
```

If you have a more elegant solution which is completely different from the approach shown here I would be more than happy to see them!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The actmov function is only run once when I close the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.gg = [line.strip("\n")]
```

This is your problem. Every iteration you're setting `self.gg` to the one-element list consisting of `line.strip("\n")`. Instead you should be setting `self.gg` to an empty list somewhere during initialization (or perhaps at the beginning of your function?) then doing `self.gg.append(line.strip("\n"))` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Works perfectly

Comment: You could also use the ugliest one-liner I've written in recent memory: `self.gg = [line.strip("\n") for line in open("usercheck.txt") if not any(exc in line for exc in map(str.rstrip, open("user.txt", "r")))]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion haha. I think I would lose track of what everything does though.

Comment: @douglasrouse yes that was the joke. Never ever do that :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you're building a `self.gg` list with only one element:

```
self.gg = [line.strip("\n")]
```

aside:

- `mmm.writelines(["%s\n"%item for item in self.gg])` could be `mmm.writelines("{}\n".format(item) for item in self.gg)`, no need to build a list, just pass the gencomp to `writelines`
- expect big performance boost in the lookup by creating a set comprehension for exclusions (if there are a lot of users): `exclusions = {line.rstrip('\n') for line in exc}`
- you could also decide to drop `rstrip` completely everywhere, you could avoid some more processing with the same result (directly use the list of strings instead of building a stripped one and dumping it back adding the linefeed)

Comment: RE: nitpicking listcomp vs genexp, I'd rather see a change from `"formatting %s this" % "like"` to `"formatting {} this".format("like")`. Either way, though....